# unable to get resolve Incomplete output stream error jclouds

Tags: java, openstack-swift, jclouds

I encountered an exception while trying to put an object using swift:

```
org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: Incomplete output stream connecting to PUT http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/v1/AUTH_2c5c2fbbfe22422496d5ebf6861199f2/myContainer1/ HTTP/1.1
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:162)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:93)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:76)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:47)
        at here`org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
        at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:79)
        at $Proxy66.put(Unknown Source)
        at com.cis.app.Appxkl.JCloudsSwift.uploadObjectFromString(JCloudsSwift.java:194)
        at com.cis.app.Appxkl.JCloudsSwift.main(JCloudsSwift.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incomplete output stream 
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)   
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:72)
        at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:141)
        ... 8 more
```

The code is:

```
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
 Payload payload = new InputStreamPayload(is);
 payload.getContentMetadata().setContentLength((long) 1000);

 ObjectApi objectApi = swiftApi.objectApiInRegionForContainer("RegionOne", CONTAINER_NAME);
 String str = "strName";
 objectApi.put(str, payload);
```

plz anyone guide me how resolve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide the correct content length instead of a bogus one, e.g.,

```
byte[] input = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
Payload payload = new InputStreamPayload(is);
payload.getContentMetadata().setContentLength(input.length);
```

You can skip the `InputStream` entirely with a `ByteArrayPayload` which sets the length automatically and provides a repeatable Payload which can deal with network timeouts and other failures:

```
byte[] input = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
Payload payload = new ByteArrayPayload(input);
```